# Who is an "ange du ménage"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

"*Ange du ménage*" literally translates as "angel of the house" or "household angel", but what does that mean? Someone acting like a guardian angel?

In context, from this article: "[Entretien avec Mère Marie-Emmanuel - Un cloître dominicain scandale de l'inutilité ? • La Porte Latine](https://laportelatine.org/activite/entretien-avec-mere-marie-emmanuel-un-cloitre-dominicain-scandale-de-linutilite)":

> Dans la communauté, il y a celles qui chantent et celles qui brodent. Celles qui font des semis et celles qui nous nourrissent. Celle qui reçoit les dons et celle qui paye les factures. Celles qui remercient et celle qui mendie. Celles qui manient la truelle, la scie ou la perceuse et celles qui enluminent. Les bibliothécaires et leurs complices de la reliure. Les lingères et les **anges du ménage**. Les sacristines et celles qui manient la pioche. Celles qui ont charge de la vie profonde des soeurs et celles qui dirigent les travaux. Celles qui décapent et celles qui peignent. Celles qui cousent et celles qui trouent. L’infirmière et ses tisanes, les polyglottes et leurs élèves, sans oublier les indispensables traductrices et correctrices ou celles qui confectionnent des chapelets. Et celle qui écrit des pièces de théâtre.

Comment: housekeeping angels

Comment: @Lambie Please don't answer in comments. If you believe an existing answer need to be improved, feel free to suggest an enhancement. If you believe a different reply would be useful, don't be shy to answer.

Comment: @jlliagre I am not answering in comments. Just giving the English which does not address the French at all, really.

Comment: @Lambie *Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.*

Comment: I was told this site was about the French language. My comment merely clarifies the translation into English, which is not the purpose of this site. I don't think it would make a good answer. faire le ménage is house cleaning though it can also be housekeeping.

Comment: @Lambie Neither a good answer nor good comments indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither guardian angels nor household.

Here, *anges du ménage* refers to the nuns who are in charge of cleaning the monastery (*faire le ménage*), the word ***ménage*** is the one found in *femme de ménage*: housekeeper, maid, and ***anges*** is a metaphor that illustrates the grace with which the nuns fulfill this task.

Comment: femme de ménage is a cleaning woman, in fact. What the British call a charwoman.